# Что такое фреймворк и как загрузить его на веб-страницу?

Tags: html, arduino, фреймворк

Пытаюсь проиграть mp3 через ардуино. Нашел пример с исходниками, не пойму, куда впихнуть код фреймворка JeeUIFramework, чтобы открылась веб-страница на телефоне. Вот такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Описание фреймворка [тут](http://jeegit.ru/2019/02/11/jeeuiframework/). Всего одна страница.
- Исходный код https://github.com/jeecrypt/JeeUIFramework
- Видео всего этого безобразия https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8Po25Sa6h0

Но там нет ни слова, как работать с фреймворком. Гугл не помог.

Comment: Вас не смутило то, что это библиотека для микроконтроллеров семейства ESP, а Arduino - это AVR?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете почитать официальную документацию данного фреймворка, так как объяснить всю его работу и как с ним работать тут - нет смысла.

> Что такое фреймворк и как загрузить его на веб-страницу?

Такой вопрос я увидел в заголовке.

*Фреймворк, с английского - рабочая среда, помогает верстальщику работать с сайтом, к примеру Bootstrap помогает создавать всякие кнопочки, поля для ввода, nav, footer и другие красивые объекты на сайте. Также есть такие фреймворки которые помогают работать с вёрсткой сайта, к примеру Vue.js.*

Comment: мне пока не нужно вдаваться в подробности его работы. мне просто нужно создать и открыть эту веб страницу.

Comment: Откройте в IDE (VSCode. например)  и скомпилируйте, как скопилировать C код в IDE? Это легко гуглится: "vscode compile main.c"

Comment: @GarfieldCat VSCode не IDE, а просто редактор кода, чистая же Visual Studio 2017, и вот-вот 2019 - IDE. Не надо вводить ТС в заблуждение

Comment: Да ладно, это в стандартной поставке. Обмажте плагинами и будет IDE. Мб тема холиварная, поэтому ничего больше сюда писать не буду.

Comment: @GarfieldCat и код компилирует? Для всех компилируемых языков. И не надо писать бред

Comment: Ребят, мне надо просто открыть эту страницу в телефоне - как на видео. Как это сделать?

Comment: Автор темы, еще раз, я окрыл и посмотрел там код на языке СИ, т.е. его надо скомпилировать и залить на, скорее всего, ардуино.

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов напиши авторам проекта данного фреймворка, там есть файлы С++, о чем пишет уважаемый GarfieldCat, мы можем лишь предпологать. Или жди реакции сообщества, возможно кто-то что-то подобное пытался делать, но ожидание не всегда быстрый вариант. Главное не ставь слово "срочно" в заголовке... о_О Ответ на первую часть твоего вопроса: фреймворк - это "библиотека" написаная ранее кем-то и которую юзают остальные (это по-простому без вики)

Comment: Ну лучше всё-же описание Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA